# mc slow to start

Tags: ubuntu, strace, mc

I log into a system via ssh (ubuntu). Recently, when I start up mc directly from the command prompt, it takes ages to start and finally present the familiar two-pane screen. Also, I can't drop to the command prompt subshell (using ctrl-o). If I start it under tmux, it starts up instantly, and ctrl-o works normally.

- running strace on mc directly: 
  http://pastebin.com/raw/br9SBZ9Y
- compared to strace on mc under tmux: 
  http://pastebin.com/raw/mYE4vMii

It seems some environment setting is causing a tremendous stall, but I can't pinpoint it. Can someone help, please?

Thanks, Jon

Comment: It appears you're trying to edit your own post with a second account ("ebahn"); either register the first one, or see http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

mc is timing out waiting for a response from `bash` (the shell it forks for the command line at the bottom of the screen).  You can find the timeout by scrolling through the timestamps.  As per `man select`, the system call in question waits for input on specified file descriptors.  In the successful trace,  FD 7 is created earlier by `pipe()` - it's a pipe to the child process.  In the successful case I found the bash prompt `jon@sonic:~$` being successfully read out of the pipe. I don't remember how I found that last, sorry.

Searching for `execv` confirms the pid which writes `jon@sonic:~$` is `bash`.  Then I happened to notice `tmux` being started somewhere in the failure case.  **I doubt `mc` likes running `tmux` as a shell!**

**You must have some sort of bash startup script which runs `tmux`.**  It avoids running it if it's already inside `tmux`.  So `mc` inside `tmux` is fine, but not outside.

I would make sure to start `tmux` from a *login* script, not the scripts which are run for bash sub-shells.  This means `.bash_profile` and not `.bashrc`.  There's some information about this here which matches my thinking: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71929/how-to-change-mc-midnight-command-bash-prompt-on-os-x

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, sourcejedi - you hit the nail on the head. I had recently added some lines to my .bashrc in order to autostart tmux on login - duh! I should have realised the connection. This is also why I couldn't drop into a subshell (using ctrl-o) from within mc. For info, the lines to start tmux were the following:

```
# enable autostart of tmux
if [[ "$TERM" != "screen" ]] ; then
# &&  [[ "$SSH_CONNECTION" == "" ]]; then
    # Attempt to discover a detached session and attach 
    # it, else create a new session

    WHOAMI=$(whoami)
    if tmux has-session -t $WHOAMI 2>/dev/null; then
        tmux -2 attach-session -t $WHOAMI
    else
        tmux -2 new-session -s $WHOAMI
    fi
fi
```

Big fail. I have now moved this into .bash_profile, and everything works! Thanks!

Jon

(btw, I'm the original poster.. hiccup with not logging in with openauth caused posting under wrong / new account)